# Power Series proofs

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

$$\alpha(x) =\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3j}}{(3j)!}$$

$$\beta(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3j+2}}{(3j+2)!}$$

$$\gamma(x) = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{3j+1}}{(3j+1)!}$$

Show that $\alpha(x+y) = \alpha(x)α(y) + \beta(x)\gamma(y) + \beta(y)\gamma(x)$ for every $x, y \in\mathbb R$.

Show that $\alpha(x)^3 + \beta(x)^3 + \gamma(x)^3 − 3\alpha(x)\beta(x)\gamma(x) = 1$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

My work:

Ive noticed that $$\sinh(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2j+1}}{(2j+1)!}$$
and $$\cosh(x)=\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2j}}{(2j)!}$$
Can hyperbolic trig identies be used to solve these and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For  the latter, notice that \begin{align*} \alpha' &= \beta, \\ \beta' &= \gamma, \\ \gamma' &= \alpha. \end{align*} Then we see \begin{align*}\frac d {dx} (\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 - 3\alpha \beta \gamma ) &= 3\alpha^2 \alpha'+ 3\beta^2 \beta' + 3\gamma^2 \gamma' - 3\alpha' \beta \gamma - 3\alpha \beta' \gamma - 3\alpha \beta \gamma' \\
&= 3\alpha^2 \beta + 3\beta^2 \gamma + 3\gamma^2\alpha - 3\beta^2 \gamma - 3\gamma^2 \alpha - 3\alpha^2\beta = 0.
  \end{align*} Thus $\alpha^3 + \beta^3 + \gamma^3 - 3\alpha \beta \gamma$ is constant. Then $\alpha(0) = 1, \beta(0) = \gamma(0) = 0$ shows that $$\alpha(x)^3 + \beta(x)^3 + \gamma(x)^3 - 3\alpha(x) \beta(x) \gamma(x) = 1, \,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb R.$$

Comment: Thank you very much, please can you explain how you noticed α′=β, β'=γ,γ′=α.

Comment: I think the key realization for that part is that $$\alpha(x) + \beta(x) + \gamma(x) = e^x.$$ Then use $$e^{x+y} = e^x e^y.$$ Of course, you could also just use the binomial theorem for $(x+y)^{3j}$ and the Cauchy product formula to multiply $\alpha(x) \alpha(y), \beta(x) \gamma(y)$ and $\beta(y) \gamma(x)$  and then compare both sides of the equation.

Comment: can you please explain how you noticed α′=β, β'=γ,γ′=α

Comment: Just perform the differentiation term-by-term. If you write out the first 5 terms in each sum and differentiate, you should see it.

Comment: Im still struggling on the first part, can you provide more hints or a head start? @user8128